# AutoDesk Inventor Export Dimensions from Design Accelerator Generated Spur Gear

Tags: gears, cad, autodesk-inventor

I'm working on modeling a turret-like mechanism in AutoDesk Inventor. Part of my design involves a rotating table. In order to accomplish this, I used the spur gear tool to generate a set of spur gears with a set center difference. One of them is an inner gear.

The generate dialog does not allow inputs to be driven by dimensions from other parts in the assembly. Additionally, the gears are generated as a phantom subassembly, and do not create an actual file in my project directory. Because of this, even though I can still export dimensions from the gears, there is no way to link other parts in the assembly to them. This is because the link dialog requires me to select a part file (which doesn't seem to exist for the gears).

As I understand it, best practice in these types of scenarios is to have one part drive the dimensions of the others to avoid messiness in the event that something needs to be resized. What's the best solution to establish a relationship between the center distance of the two gears and other parts in the assembly?